# TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python

With this code: https://github.com/SmBe19/praw-OAuth2Util

It's receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_sidebar.py", line 6, in <module>
    o = OAuth2Util.OAuth2Util(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OAuth2Util/OAuth2Util.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OAuth2Util/OAuth2Util.py", line 364, in refresh
    self._get_new_access_information()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OAuth2Util/OAuth2Util.py", line 254, in _get_new_access_information
    self._start_webserver(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OAuth2Util/OAuth2Util.py", line 229, in _start_webserver
    self.server = OAuth2UtilServer(server_address, OAuth2UtilRequestHandler, authorize_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OAuth2Util/OAuth2Util.py", line 58, in __init__
    super().__init__(server_adress, handler_class, bind_and_activate)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

By doing:

```
import praw
import OAuth2Util

user_agent = "sidebar helper"
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
o = OAuth2Util.OAuth2Util(r)
```

Is the code missing something?

Comment: You’re running it with Python 2 and it needs Python 3.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Weird. This is the version of Python that comes with RedHat and CentOS, and is the latest version on yum.

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 are essentially different languages. You’ll probably see packages called `python3`, `python3-pip` and executables `python3`, `pip3`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Feel free to make that an answer, that was it

Answer (score 0):

According to @Ryan, your problem is that you are running it in Python 2 instead of Python 3. Running it in Python 3 should fix it.